# What do the Hints in Projection deploy script generated by Vertica Database Designer mean?

Tags: database, performance, vertica

I have been searching the Vertica documentation for the meaning of certain hints in the deploy script generated by the Database Designer but have had no luck so far. 
Some of the hints like `+basename` is kind of obvious. 
But there is something called `+createtype` which is seen quite often in the auto-generated projection creation script. It looks like a function that takes in the following arguments, `L` and `D`. 
Could any one shed some light on these cryptic hints? 
I just want to to know if they are useful when creating projections manually. 
Also let me know if there is any documentation from Vertica that would help me learn more on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did post this question on both *stackoverflow* and at the *[Vertica Community-forums](http://gsfn.us/t/44htq)*. The link leads to the answer. But giving a summary here:

Hints weren't intended to be used outside the DBD. Hence undocumented.

- `createType(L)`: if projection creation was delayed meaning the table was created, but waiting for data to be inserted into the projections
- `createType(D)`: if projection was created by Database designer
- `createType(P)`: if projections were created with the projection clause